# iAd covering up buttons

Tags: xcode, swift, constraints, iad

I have an iAd banner on the bottom of my screen in my app. It is currently in testflight. I also have buttons on the bottom of the screen. The buttons have a bottom constraint set the the bottom of the view.

Do I need to set the constraint to the top of the iAd? (Since the iAd is covering up my buttons). How can I get the right constraints? Is there code to fix this? I am using Swift.

Comment: Show your view screen shot?

Comment: How are you displaying your banner ad?  In my app I have a simple line that sets canDisplayBannerAds = true.  I have a paragraph label of text constrained to the bottom margin and when the ad shows, it simply shifts the label up.  Did you uncheck the constrain to margins box when setting up the constraints?

Comment: A simple solution would be to use `canDisplayBannerAds = true` and remove your own `ADBannerView` implementation. This has its limitations, but if you only want to use the iAd network then this should get the job done.